# Querying, projecting and sorting multiple fields of documents inside a mongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a simple mongoDB collection, named usersCollection, whose generale structure is this:

```
[
  {
    "username" : "john",
    "sex" : "m",
    "email" : "john@gmail.com",
    "courses" : [
        {
           "title" : "medicine",
           "grade": 25,
        },
        {
           "title" : "art",
           "grade": 29,
        },
        {
           "title" : "history",
           "grade": 21,
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username" : "jane",
    "sex" : "f",
    "email" : "jane@gmail.com",
    "courses" : [
        {
           "title" : "math",
           "grade": 20,
        },
        {
           "title" : "medicine",
           "grade": 30,
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username" : "sarah",
    "sex" : "f",
    "email" : "sarah@gmail.com",
    "courses" : [ ]
  },
  {
    "username" : "josh",
    "sex" : "f",
    "email" : "josh@gmail.com",
    "courses" : [
        {
           "title" : "english",
           "grade": 28,
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username" : "mark",
    "sex" : "m",
    "email" : "mark@gmail.com",
    "courses" : [
        {
           "title" : "history",
           "grade": 30,
        },
        {
           "title" : "medicine",
           "grade": 19,
        },
        {
           "title" : "math",
           "grade": 22,
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Every user is a member of usersCollection and has some general informations and a list of courses that he/she has already completed with the relative grades.

Can anyone tell me how I can query usersCollection to get a descending sorted array that contains an object for all users that have already completed a specific course? Every object of this array should contains the "name", the "email" and the "grade" of the relative user.

For example, launching a query on usersCollection around the course with name "medicine", I would obtain this array:

```
[
  { 
    "username": "jane",
    "email": "jane@gmail.com", 
    "grade": 30
  },
  { 
    "username": "john",
    "email": "john@gmail.com", 
    "grade": 25
  },
  { 
    "username": "mark",
    "email": "mark@gmail.com", 
    "grade": 19
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage to do it using sort and group pipeline of mongoDB.
if you want to get any specific courses you can apply match pipeline before sort pipeline.

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$courses"
    },
    {
        $match: {
                'courses.title': 'medicine'
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            'courses.title': -1,
            'courses.grade': -1,
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$courses.title",
            records: {
                $push: {
                    "_id" : "$_id",
                    "username" : "$username",
                    "sex" : "$sex",
                    "email" : "$email",
                    "grade":"$courses.grade"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: thank you for your reply! Yes, I need to get a descending sorted array  of the users that have already completed not all possible courses, but only a specific one, for example "medicine" course excluding the others, like in my question above. Can you show me how I can do this? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: added match pipeline to get specific result.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @Shivam Mishra! It works correctly!